# SQL multiple queries response to variables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado, ole

I want to make multiple queries in single connection

I do this like

```
FileName = "d:\database.mdb"
strCnn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" & FileName
strSQL = "SELECT ID FROM [Users];SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [Users];SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM [Users];SELECT Phone FROM [Users]; "

                Set objXDatabase = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                objXDatabase.Cnn = strCnn
                objXDatabase.SQL = strSQL
                arrRst = objXDatabase.GetDatabaseArray()
                Set objXDatabase = Nothing
```

Problem is that I get error

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'  Characters found after
>   end of SQL statement.

But when I post directly into SQL Server Mananger through New query window I get normal response.

So how to get multiple response into different variables or in array so I can get each response to different variable

```
response1 = "SELECT ID FROM [Users];"
response2 = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [Users];"
responseNth = ...
```

Comment: Confusing, based on file name & provider this is *Microsoft Access* presumably, not *SQL Server*? If so please edit and re-tag

Comment: You would call `rs.NextRecordset` to navigate to the next set of results

Comment: I don't think access supports this, if it's sql server then use the [correct connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single command because it would need to return 4 separate datasets - 1 command = 1 dataset returned (even if empty).  There's no reason however to close your database connection between queries; Open the connection, execute a query to get all IDs, then a query to get distinct IDs, then a query to count the names, then a query to list the phone numbers, and finally close the connection.
Each of these would be disparate result datasets however - the IDs would not be tied to the phone numbers for instance.

Maybe try something like this....

```
FileName = "d:\database.mdb"
strCnn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" & FileName
strSQL1 = "SELECT ID FROM [Users]"
strSQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [Users]"
strSQL3 = "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM [Users]"
strSQL4 = "SELECT Phone FROM [Users]; "
Set objXDatabase = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objXDatabase.Cnn = strCnn
objXDatabase.SQL = strSQL1
arrRst1 = objXDatabase.GetDatabaseArray()
objXDatabase.SQL = strSQL2
arrRst2 = objXDatabase.GetDatabaseArray()
objXDatabase.SQL = strSQL3
arrRst3 = objXDatabase.GetDatabaseArray()
objXDatabase.SQL = strSQL4
arrRst4 = objXDatabase.GetDatabaseArray()
Set objXDatabase = Nothing
```

This is not a tested chunk of code, but rather an indication of how I think you need to proceed.  As for performance, the biggest hit is opening and closing your database connection.  Once the connection is open, running four such queries before you close it should not be a problem (depends how much data there is, but it you're using Jet and a .mdb file I'm going to guess it isn't millions of records).
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Do you can show a fully worked example ? And what about a performance?